# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in dynamic parameters node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I am trying to make a dynamic parameters in node js where the link `/eshop/edit/1111` will take you to edit a specific product but every time i try to add a product code after the  `/edit/` i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

**this is my server code**

```
router.get('/edit/:id', async (res, req) =>
{
    let id = req.params.id;
    
    let data = {
        title: `Edit product ${code} | BuckStar`,
        pageTitle: `Edit product ${code}`,
        product: id
    };

    data.res = await results.editProduct(id, req.body.category, req.body.name, req.body.description, req.body.price, req.body.amount, req.body.amount, req.body.location);

    res.render("page/create-edit", data)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here is you have the arguments in the wrong order for your handler. It should be `(req, res) =>` in that order.

Full code being:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', async (req, res) =>
{
    let id = req.params.id;
    
    let data = {
        title: `Edit product ${code} | BuckStar`,
        pageTitle: `Edit product ${code}`,
        product: id
    };

    data.res = await results.editProduct(id, req.body.category, req.body.name, req.body.description, req.body.price, req.body.amount, req.body.amount, req.body.location);

    res.render("page/create-edit", data)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct code is this as the request should come before response

```
router.get('/edit/:id', async (req,res ) =>
{

});
```

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? It's basically a copy of an answer submitted two hours before it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you exchanged the `response` and `request` parameters.

See link below for Express documentation.

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html